# Power Pivot and Closing Price

Tags: dax, powerpivot, stockquotes

I am trying to use power pivot to analyze a stock portfolio at any point in time.

The data model is:

- *transactions* table with buy and sell transactions
- *historical_prices* table with the closing price of each stock
- *security_lookup* table with the symbol and other information about the stock (whether it’s a mutual fund, industry, large cap, etc.).

One to many relationships link the symbol column in security_lookup to the transactions and historical_prices tables.

I am able to get the cost basis to work correctly by doing sumx(transactions, quantity*price). However, I’m not able to get the current value of my holdings. I have a measure called “Current Price” which finds the most recent closing price by

```
Current Price :=
CALCULATE (
    LASTNONBLANK ( Historical_prices[close], min[close] ),
    FILTER (
        Historical_Prices,
        Historical_prices[date] = LASTDATE ( historical_prices[date] )
    )
)
```

However, when I try to find the current value of a security by using

```
Current Value = sumx(transactions,transactions[quantity]*[Current Price])
```

the total is not accurate. I'd appreciate suggestions on a way to find the current value of a position. Preferably using sumx or an iterator function so that the subtotals are accurate.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. You can create additional posts for additional questions.

Comment: Edit: Removed the additional question

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `Current Value` measure is that you are evaluating `[Current Price]` within the row context of the `transactions` table (since `SUMX` is an iterator), so it's only seeing the date associated with that row instead of the last date. Or more precisely, that row's date *is* the last date in the measure's filter context.

The simplest solution is probably to calculate the `Current Price` outside of the iterator using a variable and then pass that constant in so you don't have to worry about row and filter contexts.

```
Current Value =
    VAR CurrentPrice = [Current Price]
    RETURN SUMX(transactions, transactions[quantity] * CurrentPrice)
```